# cakephp 2.5.1. can't login anymore with basic auth

Tags: cakephp, authentication

after moving to a new server the basic auth method (from app game to api service) doesn't work anymore and gives me a 401 error.

I updated the api to cake 2.5.1 and now I don't get the 401 error anymore, but I fail at this point

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
```

I can say that as I receive the }else{ message :-)

I wonder what to do know, it worked like a brise on the old server, but not on the new one.
I can install htaccess/htpasswd they work on test pages.

Only the cake basic auth method seems to make trouble.

Anyone any ideas how to investigate / solve this?

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean it "fails"? What error messages are you actually getting? Perhaps a screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: if ($this->Auth->login()) { .... }else{ return "failed at login"; } This is where I can see that I fail at the login function. I can't send a screenshot from my app...

Comment: It's not that it _fails_, as much as `$this->Auth->login()` returns false and you expect true, right?

Comment: `login` is a function - debug it and determine on what line it returns false and why.

Comment: @AgRizzo of course, you are right. I just wonder, why it was working before and why its not working yet after changing the server. Could it be a php issue?

Comment: @AD7six pls give me a hint, how can I do this? I thoughtthis is cake magic?

Comment: @AD7six I wasn't asking for that! We were talking about the cakephp login function! Your comment was not helpful!

Comment: CakePHP's source is php files, not an inpenetrable black box. If I suggest you debug some php code, and you say "pls give me a hint, how can I do this?" - then you are asking me how to debug some php code ..?